# Open-source flow visualization tool

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, data-visualization

Is there any open source Javascript-based tool with API support that can generate flow visualization like that of the [Google Analytics Visitor Flow](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1709395?hl=en-GB)?

[image]

Comment: D3 has already been mentioned but I also recommend taking a look at VisJS http://visjs.org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the D3 JavaScript library:

- http://d3js.org/ check out the example page(https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) they have some next page flow concepts